# Experiencing error: Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spacy

Okay, trying to run code that ran on other machines fine. I think it might have to do with packages?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Here is the link to github: https://github.com/chessqueen/ML
or

```
INPUT_FILE = "climate_change_health_abstract.txt"
OUTPUT_FILE = 'climate_change_health_document_sentence_vector.csv'


import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

with open(INPUT_FILE, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    all_data = fh.read()

all_data = all_data.replace("\n\n", 'XXX').replace("\n", ' ').replace("XXX", '\n')

info_pmid = re.split('(PMID: \d+)[^\n]+\n',  all_data)


def get_title(info):
    lines = info.split('\n')
    return lines[1]

def get_abstract(info):
    lines = info.split('\n')
    line_lengths = [len(line) for line in lines] # the longest one is (usually?) the abstract. KLUDGE ALERT!
    return lines[np.argmax(line_lengths)]

document_text = pd.DataFrame([{'pmid':info_pmid[i+1].replace('PMID: ', ''), 'text': get_title(info_pmid[i]) + ' ' + get_abstract(info_pmid[i])} for i in range(0, len(info_pmid) - 1, 2)])

document_text

from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe('sentencizer')

sentences = [ [sent for sent in nlp(txt).sents] for txt in document_text['text'].values]
sentences

import spacy

document_sentences = [(doc_id, sent_id, str(sent)) for (doc_id, doc) in zip(range(len(sentences)), sentences)
 for (sent_id, sent) in zip(range(len(doc)), doc)]

document_sentence_pdf = pd.DataFrame(document_sentences, columns=['document_id', 'sentence_number', 'sentence'])

sentence_encoder = spacy.load('en_use_md')
document_sentence_pdf['vector'] = [sentence_encoder(s).vector for s in document_sentence_pdf['sentence'].values]

document_sentence_pdf.head()

document_sentence_pdf[['document_id', 'sentence_number']]
```

EDIT: this is my first time coding for a project/am doing this for work and have little experience. Any help is gratefully appreciated!!

Comment: Could you split the code and run it separately, in order to isolate the source of the error?

Comment: SIGILL suggests you have an invalid processor instruction, which is really weird. Is your computer very old or otherwise unusual? If not, did you copy installed library files from another machine? You might want to with a clean virtualenv.

Comment: @polm23 Peculiar! 2020 macbook pro with m1 processor. No, totally fresh install. Should I reinstall anaconda?
I am trying to run the code just using jupyter notebooks and am now getting a kernal is dead error after line from ```from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe('sentencizer')

sentences = [ [sent for sent in nlp(txt).sents] for txt in document_text['text'].values]
sentences``` 
this chunk.

Comment: Could you maybe try not using Anaconda? Also, the error should give the line where it happened, if you could paste that output it would be helpful.